# Function restoreObject don't use Tier field?

Tags: php, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, aws-php-sdk

I'm using S3Client from PHP SDK to restore an object from Glacier and I want to use the `Expedited` flag.
I saw the documentation and I found the "Tier" field that is a **required** field but doesn't work. Standard is always used. I tried to use without the "Tier" (required) and it works and use Standard mode too.

I use this:

```
 $restoreArray = [
     'Bucket'         => $bucket,     // REQUIRED
     'Key'            => $fileName,   // REQUIRED
     'RestoreRequest' => [
         'Days'       => 1,           // REQUIRED
         'GlacierJobParameters' => [
              'Tier'  => 'Expedited', //Standard|Bulk|Expedited REQUIRED
         ],
     ],
 ];
 $client->restoreObject( $restoreArray );
```

I tried in AWS Console and the expedited tier works. With the restoreObject function is always "Standard" with or without the 'Tier' field in the array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved my problem. I had an API version 3.18.6 that have reference to the Tier field on `restoreObject` function.

But I found that it was implemented on [3.19.32](https://github.com/aws/aws-sdk-php/blob/master/CHANGELOG.md#31932---2016-11-22) version:

> Aws\S3 - Added support for Glacier retrieval tier information

Sorry for the inconvenience.